# How to return a id<protocol_type> in iOS

Tags: ios, protocols

I have a function , return a protocol.

But Xcode waring: 
[Returning 'HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult *'__strong from a function with incompatible result type 'id' ]

-----------sep line ---------------------

Question detail :

```
HpadCollectorBooleanResult.h

@protocol HpadCollectorBooleanResult <NSObject>
- (void) result:(void(^)(BOOL))block ; 
@end
```

I have a Class to implement HpadCollectorBooleanResult protocol ,
the Class is HpadMoblieCollector .

### HpadMoblieCollector.h

```
    #import "HpadCollectorResult.h"

    @interface HpadMoblieCollector : NSObject

    // clear All
    - (id<HpadCollectorBooleanResult>) favorite_ajax_clear ;

    @end
```

and the .m file is

### HpadMoblieCollector.m

```
@interface HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult<HpadCollectorBooleanResult> : NSObject
{
    void(^_result)(BOOL) ;
    BOOL isExe ;
    BOOL resultFlag ;
}

@end

@implementation HpadMoblieCollector

 // 清空手机收藏夹
- (id<HpadCollectorBooleanResult>) favorite_ajax_clear
{
    HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult *result = [[HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult alloc] init] ;
    return result ;  

// Xcode waring: 
// Returning 'HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult *'__strong from a function 
// with incompatible result type 'id<HpadCollectorBooleanResult>' 
}

@end
```

You can see , the method "- (id< HpadCollectorBooleanResult >) favorite_ajax_clear"  have an error ,
I cannot solve the problem .

1、Can you tell me why the Xcode send a warning message ?

2、Can you help me to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id<HpadCollectorBooleanResult>` means an object (`id`) that implements the **protocol** `HpadCollectorBooleanResult`.

You are creating an instance of the **class** `HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult` with `alloc [init]]`.

If `HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult` is a class you need to change the return type of your method to `- (HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult *) favorite_ajax_clear`

If `HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult` is a protocol you need to create a new class that implements that protocol. Then you can return an instance of that class. In this case it's a protocol.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <HpadCollectorBooleanResult>
- (void) result:(void(^)(BOOL))block
{
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `@interface HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult<HpadCollectorBooleanResult> : NSObject`?

Change it to `@interface HpadMoblieCollectorBooleanResult : NSObject<HpadCollectorBooleanResult>` and the warning should go away.